# CG Cookie Flex Rig Linking Problems

Tags: rigging, linked-data

I've been trying to modify CGCookie's flexrig to work in blender 2.8.
The model itself works fine in the main file. However, when I link it into another file, I start seeing strange behaviour.

1. The bone shapes meshes are visible and overlaying the actual bones, such that you can't see the shape colours.
2. When I import the rig_ui script and run it, the bone shapes lose their modifiers. Some of them have a mirror modifier, so half of the mesh appears
3. The rig itself is a bit messed up. For example the IK foot, would bend the knee backwards instead of forward. That problem doesn't exist in the original file

You can get my modified file here: https://www.openmovie.org/resources/blend-files#h.p_Jj8Qih-ybkfZ

I show a video of what's happening when I link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhUWy5b7xQs

There are some errors and circular dependencies:

```
Dependency cycle detected:
  OBrig/Parameters Component/DRIVER(pose.bones["cheek.R"].location) depends on
  OBrig/cheek.R/BONE_LOCAL() via 'RNA Target -> Driver'
  OBrig/Parameters Component/DRIVER(pose.bones["cheek.R"].location) via 'Driver -> Driven Property'
Dependency cycle detected:
  OBrig/Parameters Component/DRIVER(pose.bones["cheek.L"].location) depends on
  OBrig/cheek.L/BONE_LOCAL() via 'RNA Target -> Driver'
  OBrig/Parameters Component/DRIVER(pose.bones["cheek.L"].location) via 'Driver -> Driven Property'
Dependency cycle detected:
  OBrig/root/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() depends on
  OBrig/body_variants/BONE_DONE() via 'Copy Scale'
  OBrig/body_variants/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'
  OBrig/body_variants/BONE_POSE_PARENT() via 'Pose -> Ready'
  OBrig/root/BONE_DONE() via 'Parent Bone -> Child Bone'
  OBrig/root/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'
  OBrig/root/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() via 'Constraints -> Ready'
Detected 3 dependency cycles
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/ashehata/Software/blender_git/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - modifiers["Mask"].show_render[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/ashehata/Software/blender_git/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - modifiers["Mask"].show_viewport[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/ashehata/Software/blender_git/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - specular_hardness[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/ashehata/Software/blender_git/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - empty_draw_size[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/ashehata/Software/blender_git/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["face_variants"]["upper_lip_scale"][0]
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Kinda running out of ideas.